# Laravel 5.4 additional Auth parameters

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have added an email verification to the register process with Laravel 5.4. I am using the built-in Auth configuration as well. I want to now add a "verified" parameter to the authentication process. This used to work in earlier versions of 5.x, but I can't get it to work now.

Editing this file:

`project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

I would normally add the "verified" portion of the Login validation.

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 
                    'password' => 'required', 
                    'verified' => 1,
    ]);
}
```

This doesn't appear to be working in 5.4 now. I can login without verifed being true. Is there another way I can change this without touching any back-end classes or traits? Can I do this in the LoginController instead to make it easier to persist across Laravel upgrades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Add this to your `LoginController`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['verified' => 1]);
}
```

Never modify the core files. You can always override the core class methods in your controller.

Comment: That works. Where would I find the Laravel documentation for adding these functions?

Comment: There isn't any. You just need to explore the traits used in the auth controllers. These traits are made just to reduce the size of the controllers and move most of the logic to the core framework.

Comment: with keeping with the credentials method above, how can I tell which part failed especially the verified part? Is there an exception that is thrown? Can I wrap that in a try/catch?

Comment: For security reasons Laravel has only failure message and that is `These credentials do not match our records.` So you have no way of informing the user that their login details were wrong or their account is not verified. If you want to throw a message to them in particular if the account is not verified then you should not overwrite this method, instead override `protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user){}` in the LoginController. This method is called after a user successfully logs in. You can add additional checks here and redirect them with custom message.